# How do I delete a layer in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, html

```
[Array[5]]
 -Array[5]
  -0: Object
  -1: Object
  -2: Object
  -3: Object
  -4: Object
```

I want to archive something like this:

```
[object, object, object, object, object]
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: basically i do multiple filters and groupby

Comment: my response from server:res= [object, object, object, object, object]           vm.searchfilter = $filter('filter')( res , {category_id:$state.params.id2}, true);
                 console.log(vm.searchfilter);
                 vm.group = $filter('groupBy')(vm.searchfilter, 'model' );
                 console.log(vm.group);
                 vm.sresults = [];
                 angular.forEach( vm.group, function(value,key)
                    {
                        vm.sresults.push(value);

                    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly: either use lo-dash / underscore `_.flatten()` or do it by yourself:

```
var flattened = [];
var myArray = [[{1:1}, {2:2}, {3:3}, {4:4}, {5:5}]];

myArray.forEach(function(arr) {
  flattened = arr.map(function(item) {
    return item;
  })
});
```